# Compare Two Binary Trees

Tags: binary-tree

Given two binary search trees, write function which tells if two such trees are the same – (i.e. same info in the nodes, same branching to left and right at every node).

Comment: Incase of assignments please try first, if you get stuck somewhere you can post you code here to ask doubts.

Comment: In what language? And how does your tree data look like? 
I can give you some pseudocode if that's the goal.

Answer (score 2):

Do a breadth- or depth-first search on both trees and check each node for equality as you iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bool bst::isequal1(node *& root1,node *& root2)
{

    if(root1==NULL && root2==NULL)
    { return true;}
    if(    (root1==NULL && root2!=NULL) || (root1!=NULL && root2==NULL)   )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(  (root1->data)  !=  (root2->data)   )
    {
        return false;
    }
     return ( isequal1(root1->left,root2->left) &&
      isequal1(root1->right,root2->right));
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer